# How to show that if $P\subseteq Q$ are finite sets, and $\#P=\#Q$, then $P=Q$?

Tags: elementary-set-theory, cardinals

Let $P, Q$ two finite sets such that :
$$P \subset Q$$
$$\#P = \#Q$$

How do you show that $P = Q$ ?

I don't see how I can show that $Q \subset P$

Comment: Yes finite. That's just for $\text{#}$

Comment: What do you mean by "discrete sets"? Do you mean finite? And if so, which definition of finite are you using? (Yes, there are multiple definitions, and at the level of question you are asking the particular definition matters.) How do you define cardinality? Or do you just mean that P is equinumerous with Q?

Comment: Well, a set $E$ such that $\text{#}E \in \mathbb{N}$

Comment: With that definition, you then need to define exactly what you mean by #E. I am not trying to be difficult: as I wrote, at your level of question the definitions matter.

Comment: @Rory: The cardinality of a set. This is not an uncommon notation.

Comment: Hm it's like $Card(E)$ or $|E|$, the number of elements in $E$

Comment: In *Introduction to Mathematical Logic* by Elliot Mendelson, the OP is a significant theorem (p. 185). It uses these definitions: Finite means equinumerous with a member of the set $\omega$. Cardinal number is the smallest ordinal number equinumerous with the given set. Another definition of finite, named "Dedekind finite" in Mendelson, is almost exactly the same as the OP. That's why I am being particular in asking for the definitions. So far, the definition of cardinality is too "naïve" to be useful for a proof at this level. Or so it seems to me.

Comment: @RoryDaulton : Well if find it sufficiently convincing, and so far I didn't learn those things you mention.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $Q$ is not contained in $P,$ then there must exist an element $x \in Q$ such that $x \notin P.$ This shows that $\#P < \#Q,$ contradicting the given hypothesis.

Answer (score 1):

**HINT:** First note that there is an injective function from $Q$ into $Q$ whose range is $P$. Then use the fact that $Q$ is finite.

Comment: If we call $f$ the function, by range, you mean the image of $f$ ? Like $f(Q)$ ?

Comment: Yes, that is what I mean.

Comment: Why is there such a function for sure ? (I guess that's something obvious but I'm begginer in set theory).

Comment: Recall the definition for two sets to have the same cardinality.

Answer (score 1):

Induction on $\#Q$.

Base case: $\#P=\#Q=0$. Then $P=\emptyset=Q$.

If $\#P=\#Q=n+1$ then $P\neq\emptyset$. For some $x\in P\subseteq Q$ define $Q'=Q-\left\{ x\right\} $ and $P'=P-\left\{ x\right\} $

Then $\#P'=\#Q'=n$ with $P'\subseteq Q'$ so by induction $P'=Q'$
and consequently $P=P'\cup\left\{ x\right\} =Q'\cup\left\{ x\right\} =Q$.